# How to map ManyToMany relation? POST request

Tags: java, spring

I have two entities Worker and Speciality:

Worker:

```
@Table(name = "worker")
public class Worker {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long worker_id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinTable(name = "worker_specialities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "speciality_id"))
    private Set<Speciality> specialities = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "college_id")
    private College college;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "faculty_id")
    private Faculty faculty;
```

Speciality:

```
@Table(name = "speciality")
public class Speciality {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long speciality_id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
  private Course course;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty
  @Column(name = "active")
  private boolean active;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "speciality_id")
  private Set<Worker> workers = new HashSet<>();

  public Speciality(Course course, String name, boolean active) {
    this.course = course;
    this.name = name;
    this.active = active;
  }
}
```

WorkerController - POST

```
    @PostMapping("/worker")
    public ResponseEntity<Worker> createWorker(@RequestBody Worker worker) {
        try {
          Worker _worker = workerRepository.save(new Worker(worker.getName(), worker.getSurname(), worker.getEmail(), worker.getPhoneNumber(), worker.getSpecialities(),worker.getCollege(), worker.getFaculty()));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(_worker, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Front: Admin create Worker, choose specialities from database and assign to worker.

How to implement it in Spring? How post method should look like? (Admin can only assign specialities that already exist - so there's no need to add/edit/update speciality in worker POST.)

Comment: Thank you for response! I solve it in different way. WorkerController:   `@PostMapping("/worker")
    public ResponseEntity<Worker> createWorker(@RequestBody Worker worker) {
      try {
        Worker _worker = workerRepository
            .save(new Worker(
              worker.getSpecialities(),
              ...
            ));
 ...
`
Worker:
`   @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
    name = "specialities", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "speciality_id"))
    private Set<Speciality> specialities; `

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, if your entities have `setters` and `getters` this way:

You need to send your `worker` to `createWorker()` endpoint with `specialities` id's to find them later:

```
{
    "name": "test_worker",
    // other fields
    "specialities": [
        {
            "speciality_id": 2
        },
        {
            "speciality_id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, in `createWorker()` controller you need to replace your incomplete specialities with real:

```
@PostMapping("/worker")
public ResponseEntity<Worker> createWorker(@RequestBody Worker worker) {
    List<Speciality> specialities = (List<Speciality>) worker.getSpecialities();
    Set<Speciality> realSpecialities = specialities
                                           .map(speciality -> SpecialityService.findById(speciality.getId()))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    worker.setSpecialities(realSpecialities);

    // save worker
}
```